# WPF - CollectionViewSource Custom Sorting: Sort items within the groups, without sorting the groups themselves

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, collectionviewsource

Simple question, except for the fact that the answer seems to not exist. I've created a custom sorting method for my CollectionViewSource that sorts the collection into groups in a specific order. Now what I want to do  is sort the items within those groups alphabetically, without altering the order of the groups themselves.

I know that using `SortDescriptions`, sorting initially by a property name followed by ANOTHER SortDescrpiton for another property name will sort the items into groups and then sort the items in said groups. But I could not find such an implementation for custom sorting methods. (note: SortDescriptions does not allow for custom sorting logic, which is something I require)

I tried to create two sorting methods, one to sort into groups and the other to alphabetically sort within the groups but the second sort method received the ungrouped and unsorted original list of items for some reason.

XAML for the CollectionViewSource:

```
 <CollectionViewSource x:Key="typeFacetsByCategory" Source="{Binding Values}">
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Category" />
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
  </CollectionViewSource>
```

Code-behind:

```
        private void CustomFacetSort(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;

        if (fe == null)
            return;

        var ic = (ItemsControl)fe;
        var collection = (ListCollectionView)ic.ItemsSource;

        collection.CustomSort = new SortCategories();
        collection.CustomSort = new SortCategoriesInner();
        }
```

Ideally, the second sort method "SortCategoriesInner" would sort the already-sorted list alphabetically. Meaning `SortCategories` will sort the collection by a property named `Category`, then `SortCategoriesInner` would sort each item within the already-sorted collection alphabetically (using the property `Name`). However, `SortCategoriesInner` receives the unsorted, original list when it is assigned. When I inspect the collection after assigning `SortCategories` as the collection's `CustomSort`, the collection is indeed properly sorted by `Category`. However, when I sort the collection using `SortCategoriesInner` right after, the list is completely reset to what it was before the first sort (no longer sorted by `Category`).

I tried going into the items collection groups manually and ordering the items in each group alphabetically but they are read only so it won't work.

Comment: You should provide more information. But based on the information you provided why not to do something like this: `originalCollection.GroupBy(a=>a.Property1).OrderBy(group=>group.Key).Select(group=>group.OrderBy(a=>a.Property2))`

Comment: @Alkasai what more information would need to be provided? my issue isn't really code-related but more about how I could sort my CollectionViewSource items without changing the order of the groups themselves, I'd do it by code but it seems like the collection's CustomSort property doesn't change the original list, or resets it any time a CustomSort is provided. I'll take a look at your suggestion.

Comment: try to share what all you have tried so far.

Comment: @AbinMathew I'll add the code for the sorting but I'm not seeing how it's relevant since it seems to be more an issue with CollectionViewSource's CustomSort behavior

Comment: i'm not sure how does the `CustomSort` works but based on your code you first assign `SortCategories` and right away reassign `SortCategoriesInner`.

Comment: @Alkasai I'm not sure how it works either lol but I think assigning it will not kick off the CustomSort method right away which would explain why the next method gets the unsorted list. So I would need to find out when it actually uses CustomSort to sort the list, so I could then sort it again

Comment: I [see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.customsort(v=vs.110).aspx) `CustomSort` is `IComparer`. Anyways since you reassign the `CustomSort`, it will only have the latest value, which is `SortCategoriesInner`. and will only sort according to that. It never gets to sort based on `SortCategories`.

Comment: @Alkasai yup, I thought it would sort as soon as a comparer was assigned to it but the issue is now how to find out when the collection decides to sort the list. so that I could intercept it and sort it once more with the other sorting method. Ideally I could avoid all of this and manually go into the collection's groups by hand and sort the items but they're read-only :(

Comment: @AliEgseem that wouldn't work, because `CustomSort` seems to affect the items and not the groups. So looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) you would probably need to deal with something like [SortDescriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.sortdescriptions(v=vs.110).aspx) Property to sort the Descriptions/Groups.

Comment: @Alkasai the downside of SortDescriptions is it doesn't allow custom sorting logic. As I mention in the original post, SortDescriptions does indeed sort the items within the group but without a way of defining custom sorting logic it's not of much use to me. The need for custom sorting logic was born from this issue I had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866302/wpf-grouped-collectionviewsource-sorting-put-specific-group-at-bottom

Comment: @Alkasai After debugging, I noticed by looking through the collection.Groups property right after assigning CustomSort, the group was indeed sorted, which leads me to believe assigning CustomSort does actually sort the collection right away. What I'm guessing is that for each assignation of CustomSort, the collection will be reset.

Comment: When you look(debug) at the collection it enumerates it, the same way it would enumerate when binding to UI. So when it enumerates the collection in uses the current sorting assigned to the CustomSort.